# What was the monster that got blasted while trying to attack Moana?

Tags: moana

In *Moana*, when Moana is in the Realm of Monsters, she (almost) gets attacked by this monster:

[image: spider thing with a pink face??]

What is this monster? Does it have a basis in Polynesian mythology?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This monster was [revealed](http://disneycrossyroad.wikia.com/wiki/Sloth_Monster) to be called the ***[Sloth Monster](http://moana.wikia.com/wiki/Sloth_monster)***. Presumably this is because it's actually based on the model used for [Flash](http://disney.wikia.com/wiki/Flash) from the film Zootopia (but wearing a [traditional Polynesian mask](http://www.megapixeltravel.com/wp-content/uploads/2012/02/RON5718-Mask.jpg)).

[image]

This particular monster doesn't appear in Polynesian myth (unlike the eight-eyed bat) and was a creation of the artists, along with many of the other monsters seen;

> *The monsters in Lalotai were inspired by real fish and flora found in
> the deep sea, like angler fish and bioluminescent deep sea eels, but
> there’s also an eight-eyed bat and a monster eel from the Maui
> legends. So they’re fantastic but grounded in something real.*
>
> <sub><sup>The Art of Moana</sup></sub>

Comment: I was expecting a link to a picture of that mask. It doesn't have much of a resemblance.